# Validación de números decimales en un jtextfield en java

Tags: java

Quiero validar en un jtexfield que el usuario solo introduzca o un numero o un . pero que pueda introducir solo un punto no varios, es decir 3.3 no 3..3, tengo este código pero no se como hacer que no me introduzca los puntos repetidos, yo creo un jtexfield desde código aquí esta el código.

```
NumerosDeLaRestriccion[y] = new JTextField();
            NumerosDeLaRestriccion[y].setSize(50, 25);
            NumerosDeLaRestriccion[y].setLocation(Columna, fila);
            NumerosDeLaRestriccion[y].addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                    char caracter = e.getKeyChar();
                    if (((caracter < '0') || (caracter > '9')) && (caracter != KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)
                            && (caracter != '.') ) {
                        e.consume();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la manera que lo haces ahora solamente controlas las teclas permitidos. Si quieres asegurarte que el formato entero es valido (con un solo punto) tienes que buscarte el acceso al contenido entero del `JTextField` y comprobarlo (por ejemplo con un regex o `contains`):

```
NumerosDeLaRestriccion[y].setLocation(Columna, fila);
final TextField miJTextField = NumerosDeLaRestriccion[y];
```

...

```
if (((caracter < '0') || (caracter > '9')) 
        && (caracter != KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)
        && (caracter != '.' || miJTextField.getText().contains(".")) ) {
            e.consume();
}
```

significando:

Si la tecla no es un "." o si es un "." y el JTextField ya contiene uno (o mas) => `e.consume()`

Comment: NumerosDeLaRestriccion[y].getText().contains(".") esto me da error java me dice  `'local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final`

Comment: Si, vas a tener que asignar una referencia al TextField a una variable `final`. voy a editar.

Comment: ahora si, perfecto